# Installing Hyper-V on Windows Server 2022 reduces host system CPU to 1 core 1 thread

Tags: hyper-v, central-processing-unit, windows-server-2022

Bit of an odd situation, I've installed Windows Server 2022 (desktop experience) on a server, installed MegaStorage MSM and the relevant drivers from Supermicro and any Windows updates. When I install the role HyperV (just the Windows feature Hyper V, not any VMs), my host goes from 8c16t to 1c1t.
I thought it might be a visual bug, but it runs like a snail stuck in syrup, so it seems like it's running on 1c. The L1 and L2 caches reported by Task Manager are also altered, but the reported caches are 1/8s of total cache, so it fits the core reduction.

I'm not experienced with Server 2022, and I've only really set up HyperV and VMs on Windows 7/10/11 as well as VirtualBox previously, so it's entirely possible this is amateur hour and I've forgotten to set/install something basic and obvious.

As for the usual suspects, I've double checked BIOS settings (originally set by the hardware supplier) and everything VT-related looks enabled. The msconfig -> Boot -> Advanced -> "Number Of Processors" check box is unchecked.

I suppose maybe the correct way to do it is to use HyperV 2019 (since MS has not released a 2022 version) as the host, and use my licensed 2022 as the guest VM, I'll try that next as the supplier suggested it might be a Server 2022 software issue.

The system in question:

```
Motherboard: Supermicro X11SPL-F running 3.6 BIOS
CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4208SP 8c16t
RAM: 16GB DDR4 3200MHz ECC Registered 2Rx8 Samsung x4
Controller: Avago/Broadcom/LSI/whatever the flavour of the month SAS9341-8i
Storage: 2x Samsung PM883 SSD 960GB running RAID1
```

Here are screenshots of the feature list, Task Manager and Device Manager before and after:
https://ibb.co/v1mP8Zn
https://ibb.co/6Z6xj7C

Update: I installed Windows Server 2019 (evaluation edition, no license) and this doesn't happen at all. HyperV goes in, CPU remains 8c16t. I upgraded that install with HyperV enabled from Server 2019 (eval) to Server 2022 (licensed) and the upgrade reduces my host CPU to 1c1t.

#2: Edit: Corrected feature to role.

I went through the logs and there's an error being thrown just after HyperV is installed.

Event 97: "Hypervisor processor startup failed (APIC ID 0x0) due to CPUID feature validation error. Further processors in the system were not started. Leaf 0x1, register 0x2 feature mismatch: BSP has features 0x77FEFBF7; AP has features 0x0".
I see other people have reported this error for previous Windows Server versions.

My exact CPU specs are:

```
Processor Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4208 CPU @ 2.10GHz
Type : 0 Family : 6
Model : 55
Stepping : 7
Revision: 500320A
```

Comment: this is just a guess, but might it be because hyper-v is no longer free and you maybe have not licensed it.

Comment: I have licensed and activated the Server 2022 install, if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes, should be fine on an activated Server Version.

Comment: As mentioned, my install is licensed, but the problem remains.

Comment: have you checked in msconfig > boot > Advanced options... if the setting Number of processors is set?

Comment: Indeed, I've checked that. You'll find that listed in the third paragraph in my original post. I contacted my supplier(s) and they blame Microsoft. Joy.

Comment: The X11SPL-F isn't certified for Win2022 (it is for 2016 and 2019) and its firmware might not be compatible - Supermicro lists the X11SPL-F as only compatible with Hyper-V 2016: https://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/OS/C621.cfm

Comment: Thanks for that Zac67, good to know. As per Sanders reply, I checked my BIOS, and while I don't have the Extreme setting, changing from Maximum Performance to "just" Performance did indeed fix the issue for me. Thank you Sander, I doubt I'd even attempt that toggle without your post.

Comment: @Zac67 Just as an update, I mentioned this in correspondence with my supplier/Supermicro. They said not to be concerned and pointed to the fact that Supermicro provides Windows Server 2022 drivers for X11SPL-F. I find the contradiction a bit strange, though. I see other manufacturers have Server 2022 compatibility listings for C621A, which seems to be a newer revision of C621. I compared the chipsets and they seem fairly similar, but I'm no expert. At this point I'm content with Sanders workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same behavior with one of two servers in a HyperV Failovercluster.

Host1 and Host2 shows all cores/cpu's in Device Manager, but Host1 only runs on one core and one CPU. Also visible in TaskManager.

Reinstalled, new BIOS, reset BIOS, latest updates. Supermicro distributor is trying to help, but no clue...
No difference in hardware and (software) versions.

**EDIT: Got it!** My colleague searched and searched for it. And found a **workaround**!
Ok, the workaround is nasty and shows a problem in how HyperV 2022 in somewhere in the latest Windows Updates communicates with the BIOS and CPU.

In the BIOS, go to `Advanced -> CPU Configuration -> Advanced Power Management Configuration -> "ENERGY_PERF_BIAS_CFG mode"`. Edit this option.
You will find six options;

- Extreme Performance (does not work)
- Maximum Performance (does not work)
- Performance (works)
- Balanced Performance (works)
- Balanced Power (works)
- Power (works)

See following screenshot as example:
[BIOS screenshot of powermanagement templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4t3y.png)
Select one of the working templates and you will get back CPU cores.

**But why?!** It looks like there is something wrong with the exposure of the CPU C-states. In this particular situation is looks like it have to do something with CPU masks and with HyperV not accepting/recognizing them:
**"Extended Auto-HALT State C1E"**

Sander.

Comment: That is interesting, and I'll have a look at my BIOS for sure. For the sake of curiosity, would you mind posting the specs for your two hosts? CPU/motherboard will likely be sufficient. Thanks for posting your findings.